Añadir assets a mi proyecto en Flutter - ¿Cómo sé si realmente estoy teniendo un problema al agregar assets a Flutter?
Estoy tratando de agregar activos a mi proyecto de Flutter editando el archivo pubspec.yaml. Sin embargo, al intentarlo como marca el archivo, estoy obteniendo un error.
¿Cómo puedo asegurarme de que estoy agregando correctamente los activos y evitando problemas con mi configuración de assets en Flutter?
Acá mi archivo 'pubspec.yaml':
    # The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - images/dog.jpg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

Y el error que me muestra es el siguiente:

The asset file 'images/dog.jpg' doesn't exist. Try creating the file or fixing the path to the file.

Esta es la forma como están mis archivos:


No agregues imágenes dentro de /lib, agregalas dentro de /assets

El problema es que de acuerdo a tu archivo pubspec.yaml, tu directorio /images debe encontrarse en la raiz de tu proyecto, lo cual no es así ya que esta dentro de /lib.
Te sugiero crear un directorio /assets agregar tu directorio /images,

y especificar la ruta de la imagen en tu  pubspec.yaml de esta forma:
assets:
      - assets/images/dog.jpg

